# Can C# interfaces implement lists or arrays? If so, how?

Tags: c#, typescript, class, interface, .d.ts

I am translating a bunch of typescript classes and interfaces to C# (for javascript interop for those wondering why)

One example that I am not sure how to translate from typescript is this:

```
interface CellArray extends Array<Cell> {
    addClass(className: string): CellArray;
    removeClass(className: string): CellArray;
    html(html: string): CellArray;
    invalidate(): CellArray;
}
```

If i'm reading that correctly, that interface is extending the type of an array of type cell... while also having some return methods.

Is there a way to translate this to C#?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably mean *interfaces that **extend** other interface* - not **implement** .....

Comment: You obviously can't https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#interfaces-extending-classes in C#, so probably `interface CellArray : IList<Cell>` is the best you can get... Explaining how you plan to use the result may help someone to suggest an approach so.

Comment: Alexei, interface CellArray : IList<Cell> was what i needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# interfaces cannot directly inherit from Lists (because they are classes) - but they can inherit from any interface such as `IList` or `IEnumerable`:

Array is a class which inherits from `IList` and `IEnumerable`. So you can inherit from `IList<T>`

```
    public interface Test<T> : IList<T>
    {
        // code here
    }
```

Or you can inherit from `IEnumerable`:

```
    public interface Test<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        // code here
    }
```